# How to Change the Font Color of Individual Characters Within a Cell in Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that we use for our crew list at work.  Within certain cells we have alpha/numeric information that we use for time-keeping purposes.  i.e. CLAAO10I - the use of 0, 1, I, and O could be used in any order or not at all (could be all alpha or all numeric characters).

What VBA code would I use to automatically change the letters I and O to the color Red in the following cells:  F6, F11, F16, F21, L6, L11, L16, L21, R6, R11, and R21 to help differentiate between the numbers 0 and 1 and the letters I and O?

Comment: Did you already try to do it by hand, and record a macro while doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range.Characters(start, length)` to access a specific character in a cell and `Range.Characters(start, length).Font.Color` to colorize a specific character.

So you would need one loop to go through all cells in a given range. And one loop to go through all characters in each of these cells and colorize them as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorizeLetters()
    Dim iChar As Long

    Dim Cel As Range
    For Each Cel In Worksheets("YourSheet").Range("F6,F11,F16,F21,L6,L11,L16,L21,R6,R11,R21")
        For iChar = 1 To Cel.Characters.Count
            Select Case Cel.Characters(iChar, 1).Text
                Case "O", "I"
                    Cel.Characters(iChar, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                Case "1", "0"
                    Cel.Characters(iChar, 1).Font.Color = vbGreen
            End Select
        Next iChar
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Note that this only works for constant cells, and you cannot colorize specific characters if the cell contains a formula.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peh.  We unfortunately do have formulas in those cells so it won't work for our purposes.

Comment: @Kelly Then this is not possible at all. Excel does not support colorizing single characters in formulas. This is an Excel limitation.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
Sub makeRedSubstrings()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cll As Range, rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' change sheet below as required
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F6,F11, F16, F21, L6, L11, L16, L21, R6, R11, R21")

    For Each cll In rng
        For i = 1 To Len(cll)
            If Mid(cll, i, 1) = "I" Or Mid(cll, i, 1) = "O" Then
                cll.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
            End If
        Next i
    Next cll

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Miqi180, thanks for your reply, however it looks as though your answer has the same issues as Peh's - (it doesn't work if there is a formula already in the cell).

Comment: In that case you want to do something quite different here, since your post didn't say anything about formulas. You could insert the formulas as text in comments in each of the respective cells, and then add different font colors but, this is an entirely different question from what you posted. As `PEH` already pointed out, Excel does not support coloring of formulas inside cells.